# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, windowsce

Estoy haciendo un proceso en segundo plano, pero estoy teniendo problemas,  lo que necesito es que mientras estoy haciendo un proceso de insercion de datos en el servidor, un proceso en segundo plano este verificando el estado de la transaccion.
el codigo del proceso que verifica en segundo plano es este:
con un delegado hago el llamado a la funcion que esta verificando en el serviodor cada 5000 milisegundos y si detecta un estado haga una cosa y si detecta otra haga otra, por ejemplo que si detecta el estado de **RETENIDA** pues cierre el formulario y si el estado es **CANCELADA** hace un proceso distinto, este proceso de verificacion de estado se corre hasta que detecta alguno de los dos estados ya dichos, se termina, mientras esto se esta corriendo, en primer plano se esta insertando datos en otra tabla

```cs
    private delegate void UpdateStatusDelegate();
    Thread verifyStatusOnServer;

    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          verifyStatusOnServer = new Thread(new 
          System.Threading.ThreadStart(verifyStatusOfTransaction));
          verifyStatusOnServer.Start();
          verifyStatusOnServer.IsBackground = true;   
    }

    public void verifyStatusOfTransaction()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                try
                {
                    DataTable tempVerifyStatus = new DataTable();
                    tempVerifyStatus = this.db.verifyStatusMovilAlways(tipoTransaccion, numeroTransaccion, Shared.RETENIDA);
                    if (tempVerifyStatus.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        DataRow row = tempVerifyStatus.Rows[0];
                        if (Shared.RETENIDA.Equals(row[0].ToString()))
                        {
                            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusDelegate(transactionChangeStatusToRetenida));
                            }
                            verifyStatusOnServer.Abort();
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (Shared.CANCELADA.Equals(row[0].ToString()))
                        {
                            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                this.Invoke(new UpdateStatusDelegate(transactionChangeStatusToCancelada));
                            }
                            verifyStatusOnServer.Abort();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("¡La transacción ha pasado a RETENIDA!" + error.InnerException.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                }
            }
            this.Hide();
        }
```

este es el codigo que hace la verificacion, que ese estado no haya cambiado en la tabla, entonces mientras el proceso de insercion se esta corriendo que es un poco lento, cae en este bloque de codigo, exactamente en **SqlDataAdapter**  y me da el error que tiene como titulo esta pregunta

```cs
public void finishTransactionsMovilMovimiento( string position, string typeTransaction, int numberTransaction, int line)
        {
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("TransactionBegin");
            try
            {

                this.command.Parameters.Clear();
                this.command.Parameters.Add("@numero", position);
                SqlDataReader reader = this.command.ExecuteReader();
                transaction.Commit();
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Problema al tratar de actualizar los datos en el servidor, intente nuevamente. Error: " + error.Message);
            }
        }
```

todo esto es para un dispositivo con windows CE 6.0 Pro, con compact framework 3.5

Comment: este codigo que muestras ejecuta dentro del windows CE ?

Comment: configuras MARS en el connection string ?

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice leandro, donde esta el reader que protesta?

Comment: siii ahi lo estoy ejecutando, pero para debuggear lo hago en un emulador de pocket pc, que tiene las mismas caracteristicas que el otro dispositivo

Comment: esta aproximadamente en la linea 16 del segundo cuadro de de codigo que se muestra

Comment: Leandro te refieres a esto: **MultipleActiveResultSets=True** en el connection string? si es eso, pues no me funciono, ya probe pero nada

Comment: Es porque no cerraste algún DataReader. Proba cerrando tanto la conexión como el DataReader/SQLDataAdapter en el control de la excepción, tal vez están quedando conexiones abiertas. Puedes hacerlo en el `finnaly` del catch.

Comment: ¿Tienes que utilizar la misma conexión por alguna razón particular?

Comment: ya logre solucionarlo, haciendo una conexion diferente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion que le pude dar fue, que tuve que hacer una conexión extra, y aislada a solo ese procedimiento para que no de problemas

```
     public DataTable verifyStatusMovilAlways(string parametros, int parametros, 
     string parametros)
        {
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn =  new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT ...;";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@parametros", parametros);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@parametros", parametros);

                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        adapter.Fill(tabla);
                        adapter.Dispose();
                    }
                    conn.Close(); 
                }
                return tabla;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Problema En Segundo plano. Error: " + e.Message);
                return tabla;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo esta respuesta. En que se diferencia este codigo del que tenias antes? Es exactamente el mismo codigo. O yo no logro ver la diferencia...

Comment: Los objetos que implementan la interface IDisposable lo mejor es tratarlos con using, he ahí la diferencia donde instancia la conexión y el SqlCommand.